# IllegalStateException with PagerAdapter when setting current item

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I am using a `ViewPager` with a custom `PagerAdapter` to show a gallery. 
The gallery can receive a new object through the method `onObjectReceived()`; if the position of the new object is less than or equal to the current position, the current position of the gallery is updated to avoid the change of page.

```
ViewPager gallery;
PagerAdapter galleryAdapter;

@Override
public void onObjectReceived(Object object, int position) {
  if(galleryAdapter != null) {
      galleryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      if(position <= currentPosition)
          gallery.setCurrentItem(++currentPosition);
  }
}
```

Even if I am calling `notifyDataSetChanged` before setting the new position, I am getting the following exception:

```
IllegalStateException: The application's PagerAdapter changed the adapter's content without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged
```

at the line

```
gallery.setCurrentItem(++currentPosition);
```

How can I solve this problem?

P.S.: I have not overriden `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Are you using a PagerAdapter or FragmentPagerAdapter ?

Comment: I implemented PagerAdapter

Answer (score -1):

had similar problem. the notifyDataSetChanged only work if u can call in time.

for my case, similar to ur, it did not work for me by calling it right before I need the page changes.  I solved it by creating a new adapter instance.  not too happy about it but that worked.